# load and remove html content div with jquery

Tags: jquery, load

I am trying to load and remove external html file on div click using jquery, it works on remove, but it does not work when it must load back the content. Here the html:

```
        <nav id="select-car">
         <div id="gamma">
         </div>
         <div id="arrows" class="arrow-right"></div>
        </nav>
```

And here the jquery:

```
$('#gamma').load('nav-gamma.html');
    $("#arrows").click(function(){
     $('#arrows').toggleClass('arrow-left arrow-right');
     if ($('#gamma').html().length>0){$('#gamma ul').remove();}
     if ($('#gamma').html().length<=0){ $('#gamma').load('nav-gamma.html');}
    });
```

any idea how it does work? thank you

Comment: I guess, `$('#gamma').html().length` is never equal to 0 (and negative of course)...  You should trim it or better check for `$('#gamma ul').length`

Comment: what i must use then? have you any suggestion?

Comment: I edited previous comment. But anyway, seems relatively easy to debug your code and check what's going wrong. EDIT: AND you should use `if/else if` blocks in fact

Comment: Try - if(!$.trim( $('#gama').html() ).length)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for. Be careful when putting <div> and </div> and try to use length (spaces, tabs are also characters that add to the length.
Working plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/5XJO2lp02zhbUAdKR22y

Javascript

```
$('#gamma').load('nav-gamma.html');
$("#arrows").click(function(){
 $('#arrows').toggleClass('arrow-left arrow-right');
 if ($('#gamma').html().length>0)
  {
    $('#gamma ul').remove();
  } 
 else if($('#gamma').html().length<=0)
 {
   $('#gamma').load('nav-gamma.html');

 }
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="gamma"></div>
```

Comment: it works but for me for some strange reason seems not working, i try with workaround

Comment: Make sure you wrap your jquery code with a $(document).ready(function () { YOUR_CODE_HERE }); It's possible that your code runs before the DOM is initialized. See the plunker for example.

Answer (score 0):

i tried with different approach:

```
    setTimeout( function(){$('#gamma h3').toggleClass('visible not-visible');} , 500);
    setTimeout( function(){$('#gamma').toggleClass('closed1');},500);
```